# Allow user to only enter string as answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to have a User only be allowed to type in letter, this is what i have tried so far, but when the user enter a number or anything else, the Console App Just continues.

```
 static public string Ask(string question)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write(question);
            return Console.ReadLine();

        } while (Regex.IsMatch(Console.ReadLine(), @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"));

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't return inside the loop.  Create a `string input` variable and assign that in the loop, then when the loop exits return the `input` variable.

Comment: ya your returning in the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are returning the result of first `Console.ReadLine()` so your loop never continues to the `while` clause.

What you need to do is create a string variable and assign the value, then check it in your while clause:

```
public static string Ask(string question)
{
    string input;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(question);

        //Assigns the user input to the 'input' variable
        input = Console.ReadLine();

    } //Checks if any character is NOT a letter 
    while (input.Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x)));

    //If we are here then 'input' has to be all letters
    return input;
}
```

Notice I am also using Linq's `Any()` instead of Regex.  Seems easier to me, and it *might* be faster (too lazy to benchmark).

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TDiNRu)

Comment: wow that Any() just blew my mind, didn't know there is such a simple solution to this. thank you a lot. I also added Console.WriteLine("Only Letters Allowed"); just to make it more clear for the user. thank you a lot.

Comment: @Robertme Start taking a look at Linq, its a game changer in C#/.NET

Comment: Can you recommend me any tutorials or website where i can look into it, i really want to learn c# :)

Comment: @Robertme The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) are a good place to start.

Comment: Could you maybe explain the (x => !char.IsLetter(x))); mainly the x => is what i never really seen before

Comment: @Robertme the `x => ` part is a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).  Basically an "anonymous function".  Essentially this expression is like asking: if any character in `input` (`x =>`) is _not_ a letter (`!char.IsLetter(x)`).